# How to return combinations generated from recursive function to outside?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I need to solve the following task recursively:

> Find combinations of ways to climb a stair case, you can take only
> one or two steps at a time.

For example, for `n = 3`, it should output `[1,1,1],[2,1],[1,2]`.

This is what I got so far:

```js
function num_ways(n, alreadyTakenSteps) {
  var output = [];
  if (n == 0) {
    console.log(...output, ...alreadyTakenSteps);
    return [...output, ...alreadyTakenSteps];
  }
  
  if (n >= 1) {
    var res1 = num_ways(n - 1,  [...[1], ...alreadyTakenSteps]);
    if (res1.length) {
      output=[...output, ...res1];
    }
    //console.log(res1);
  }
  
  if (n >= 2) {          
    var res2 = num_ways(n - 2, [...[2], ...alreadyTakenSteps]);
    output=[...output, ...res2];
  }
  
  return output;
}

var output = num_ways(3, []);
console.log(output);
```

In the stop-condition (first if-statement), I output the result. There, all outputs are fine. But the overall returned value is wrong (see output of `console.log(output)`).

How can i make this working?

Comment: `[ ...[1], ...]` is the same as `[1, ...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there are no more steps to take you need to encapsulate the walk/array. So instead of **return [...output,...alreadyTakenSteps];**  do **return [...output,...[alreadyTakenSteps]];**

```
function num_ways(n,alreadyTakenSteps) {
    var output=[];
    if (n == 0) {
      console.log(...output,...alreadyTakenSteps);
      return [...output,...[alreadyTakenSteps]];
      
    }
    if (n >= 1) {
     
      var res1=num_ways(n - 1,  [...[1],...alreadyTakenSteps]);
      if(res1.length){
        output=[...output,...res1];
      }
     //console.log(res1);
    }
    if (n >= 2) {          
      var res2= num_ways(n - 2, [...[2],...alreadyTakenSteps]);
      output=[...output,...res2];
    }
    return output;
  };
 var output= num_ways(3,[]);
 console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you.it works fine ,can you please explain this magical code `[...output,...[alreadyTakenSteps]]`

Comment: Its the same as your [...[1]] ends up as [1]. so [...[[1,2,3]]] ends up as [[1,2,3]].  When you combined your arrays with [...output,...rest1]  you get something like [...[[1,2]],...[[2,1]] and that leaves you with [[1,2],[2,1]]

Comment: totally make sense ,Thank you

Comment: @RalphRitoch Do you recommend `...[alreadyTakenSteps]` over `alreadyTakenSteps`? If not, then why did you use it? You could've brought memory-usage up. Personally, I think SO answers should not only answer the question, but allow the readers to learn maybe even something outside the scope of the question, as they might not have learned about it any other way.

Comment: @Oskar Grosser, my solution solves the problem, if not solving the problem uses less memory, and you need to solve the problem, then the solution that uses less memory but doesn't' solve the problem is useless!

Comment: @OskarGrosser I never intended to provide the most optimized solution, I provided the solution which was easiest from the current code. Over-optimizing may be fun in theory, but it is a gross waste of time and money in the real world.

Comment: @RalphRitoch I agree on "Over-optimizing (...) is (mostly) a waste of time and money", but code such as `...[x]` shouldn't be something that come's up in one's mind as a solution for the problem at hand. This could've been taught here. Also, your argument "I provided the solution which was easiest from the current code" isn't really a strong one, as one could've removed the spread-operator instead of adding an array.

Comment: @OskarGrosser removing the spread operator may have worked but it wouldn't demonstrate that we are encapsulating it.  This change matched the style of the remaining code.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to point out a perhaps cleaner implementation of the same idea.

```js
const climbStairs = (n) =>
  n < 1 
    ? [[]] 
    : [
        ... climbStairs (n - 1) .map (p => [1, ... p]),
        ... (n > 1 ? climbStairs (n - 2) .map (p => [2, ... p]) : []),
      ]

console .log (climbStairs (5))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If there are no stairs remaining, there is only one path, up them, the empty path.  If there's at least one, then we can take one step up and recur on the remaining stairs, or, if there are at least two stairs, then we can take two steps up and recur on the remainder.  The `.map` calls just combine our current step with each of the recursive results.

One nice thing about this is how well it maps to the similar counting problem, where we don't want to list all the paths, but only to count them.  Note how close this is to `climbStairs`:

```js
const nbrOfWays = (n) =>
  n < 1 
    ? 1
    : nbrOfWays (n - 1) + 
      (n > 1 ? nbrOfWays (n - 2)  : 0)
  

console .log (nbrOfWays (5))
```

Comment: Thank you.Pretty neat code compare to mine

Answer (score 0):

## Your problem

Now, the only problem with your code is in case `n == 0`.
Here, you currently return an array containing the elements of `alreadyTakenSteps`. This is wrong, because the return-value is then destructured, which results in losing the combination of a way among other destructured ways.

You can imagine it like this:
Currently, you return a way of taking the steps, which is then destructured and placed next to other destructured ways. We are essentially missing the ways among themselves, as we remove the arrays which identify them.

Instead, we want to return an array containing the ways. *That* array will then be destructured, placing all the different ways in one array. This will result in an array containing all the ways.

Simply put:
In case `n == 0`, return `[alreadyTakenSteps]`; return the existing way in a wrapper-array.

## Thoughts on refactoring

- All statements of the form of `...[x]` will result in `x`. It basically creates an immediately destructured array, which may impact memory-usage for a large `n`.
  Just change it to `x`.
- The use of `var` has become somewhat obsolete, as it can be replaced by either `let` or `const` in most cases.
  Using `var` is not a problem, but the alternatives may convey more meaning (e.g. the reference of a `const` is *never* changed, the reference of a `let` *may* be changed).
- We can use [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) to simplify the call of `num_ways()`; more precisely, we can default the `alreadyTakenSteps`-parameter to `[]`:
  `function num_ways(n, alreadyTakenSteps = []) { ... }`
  With this, a call could look like `num_ways(3)`, but we can still pass the second argument in case we want to extend some already taken steps.
- Case `n == 0`:
  You are destructuring the empty `output`-array, effectively doing nothing. In this case, `output` actually doesn't need to be initialized yet.
  This means, it can be rewritten to `[alreadyTakenSteps]` (incorporating the solution from before), with `var output = [];` *after* this if-statement.
- Case `n >= 1`:
  The inner `if (res1.length)` is unnecessary, since we pass `[1, ...alreadyTakenSteps]` as the second argument, which contains at least `1` as an element.

## Afterthoughts

What I personally dislike is your way of re-instantiating the output-array for cases `n >= 1` and `n >= 2`. This can be circumvented by using more cases.

Here is my implementation of the task. Difference between yours and mine is, that mine  will return an empty array instead of an array containing an empty array.
Semantically, this would be equal to…

- …you saying: "There is a way: You may take 0 steps."
- …me saying: "There is no way: You cannot climb such *'stairs'*."

```js
console.log(recursiveNumWays(3));

function recursiveNumWays(n, arr = []) {
  if (n == 0) return arr;
  if (n == 1) return [1, ...arr];
  
  const ways1 = recursiveNumWays(n - 1, [1, ...arr]);
  const ways2 = recursiveNumWays(n - 2, [2, ...arr]);
  
  if (n == 2)
    return [ways1, ways2];
  if (n == 3)
    return [...ways1, ways2];
  
  return [...ways1, ...ways2];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important;top:0}
```